# Special relativity effects in rotational reference frame

Tags: special-relativity, doppler-effect

If I am sitting in the rotational reference frame, it is very easy to get some objects moving with the speed of light in relation to me. For example, the average distance to the Moon is 384400 km. If I am rotating in a way, that one rotation takes 8 seconds, then Moon in relation to me will move in a circle and Moon will do 1 full rotation in 8 seconds. if radius of this Moon rotation is 384400 km and time is 8 seconds, then Moon will travel the distance
$$S=2\pi R=2\pi \cdot384400=2415256\ km$$

Moon's speed will be

$$V=\frac{2415256\ km}{8}=301907\ \frac{km}{s}$$
if I take not 8 seconds but 8.06 then Moon's speed will be

$$V=\frac{2415256\ km}{8.06}=299659\ \frac{km}{s}$$

which is almost exactly the speed of light.

In this case, I should see the Moonlight as redshifted due to Transverse Doppler effect as mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect#One_object_in_circular_motion_around_the_other) (Figure 5b). The Moon should become completely black because with the exact speed of light all frequencies will be 0.

Of course, I do not know exact distance to the Moon at the current moment, but as I calculated, even if I make 40000 km mistake (if Moon is at max distance but I was thinking it is min), then still purple color (400nm) will become red color (800 nm) and I should see the Moon as red, not white as usual.

Looks like it is quite easy to observe and make this experiment. Did anyone try it already or why it will not work? The Moon is the perfect object for this.

Comment: "If I am rotating in a way, that one rotation takes 8 seconds" You can do it yourself by spinning in place. This does show that there is something wrong with your theoretical predictions, and this might be a really interesting educational "paradox". I didn't check it in details, but I find it possible that the fact the reference frame is not inertial will alter greatly the formulae you assumed to hold true (I didn't read the Wikipedia article in detail).

Comment: The light that comes from the Moon does not know that it comes from the Moon. It could have come from an image of the Moon ten feet away from you. Would the Doppler effect still make the image of the Moon appear black? If not, then why should the Moon go black?

Comment: @FlatterMann We have a well-known effect when the light from far galaxies comes red-shifted. You could say the same, that light does not know that it comes from far galaxies, why should it be red shifted?

Comment: @NíckolasAlves This is what they say in Wikipedia, it should come redshifted. Looks like I need to check who added this paragraph to Wikipedia and the history of this article.

Comment: @Zlelik The red shift is caused by an actual motion of those galaxies relative to us. The Moon, however, does not move an inch, no matter how fast your chair rotates. This is, at least in principle, experimentally testable. We can send a light beam to both and see if we will ever get a return signal. In case of the moon we will and we have, but most observable galaxies have left our sphere of influence. Even a light signal will never reach them. That your Gedankenexperiment comes to the wrong conclusion is also testable. Rotate your chair on a moonlit night and see if the Moon goes red.

Comment: @FlatterMann The main point of the Special Relativity is that there is no special universal reference frame and the statement "The Moon, however, does not move an inch" does not make any sense without mentioned relatively to what Moon does not move an inch. If I am staying on the Earth and spaceship is moving in relation to the Earth with speed close to speed of light, then I will see all special relativity effects in the spaceship. Person who is in the spaceship will see the same special relativity effects on the Earth if will be looking to the Earth at me.

Comment: @FlatterMann 
I added UPDATE 1 with the details why I am referring to Wikipedia article. If you really want to help try to explain why Wikipedia article is wrong or why I am applying it in the wrong way.

Comment: @Zlelik I have reverted your UPDATE 1 edit. In your title you ask about the rotating reference frame, as you also do in your original question. You received correct answers to that question. The edit, asking about the momentarily co-moving frame, makes the already received answers incomplete, which is against the site policy. You should never edit a question in a way that invalidates otherwise valid answers to the original question.

Comment: @Dale I do not agree that any provided answers are correct. They all ignore my reference to Wikipedia article and Figure 5b in the main question. My update was only clarification about this reference and Figure 5b.

My question was "Why it will not work?" and the correct answer suppose to refer to Wikipedia article and Figure 5b and explain why it is not applicable or why Wikipedia article is wrong. All the answers gives the generic answer that rotational frame is not inertial frame. But in this Wikipedia article they explain why it can be used.

Answer (score 1):

The laws of physics have the simplest form in all *inertial* reference frames. A rotating reference frame is NOT inertial, and so all equations need adjusting to account for that. For example in a rotating reference frame there is an apparent centripetal force away from the hub, so Newton's laws need to be changed to incorporate that. Similarly, equations for doppler shift will have terms that account for the rotation of the frame, and those terms will cancel out any apparent doppler shift that you might expect from naively treating the rotating frame as inertial.

Comment: In the question, I posted a link to Wikipedia, where it is mentioned that there will be a red shift in exactly this situation. Do you think this paragraph in Wikipedia is wrong or I am reading it the wrong way? If yes, could you please give the equation or put a link to it, which will work in this situation and cancel out the doppler shift?

Comment: I don't see any such claim in the wikipedia article. In fact the whole subsection labeled "Source and receive both in circular motion around a common center" describes how Doppler shifts need not occur, and in particular note the sentences "...the difficulty of analyzing a relativistic scenario often depends on the choice of reference frame. Attempting to analyze the scenario in the frame of the receiver involves much tedious algebra. It is much easier, almost trivial, to establish the lack of Doppler shift between emitter and absorber in the laboratory frame." This applies to your scenario.

Comment: Moreover, it is trivially easy to experimentally establish that there is no such Doppler shift:  go outside at night and observe the Moon. Now start spinning around and observe the Moon as it passes before your eyes. Its color does not change.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to confuse me and all the people who will read this question later instead of helping. I added an update 1 to clarify which section of the Wikipedia article I am referring to. I am referring to section "One object in circular motion around the other" and Figure 5b, you are referring and citing different section "Source and receiver both in circular motion around a common center" and Figure 6, which is different scenario. I agree with you, that in figure 6 there will be no red shift, but I am asking about Figure 5b.

Comment: ALL of the Wikipedia article is about actual motion, and there's no reference in it to coordinate effects (such as using a rotating coordinate frame), so none of the sections in that article exactly match your scenario. To see the difference, consider the path of the light from the Moon to your eye. If you are using rotating coordinates, the path comes out as a spiral, not a straight line, and the speed of any particular beam of light is no longer a simple constant, it's a complicated expression that depends on its distance from you.

Comment: But this is one of the main points of the Special Relativity, that there is no special actual reference frame and the statement "about actual motion" doesn't make sense because there is no actual motion. All motion is relative to something. If I am on the Earth and spaceship is moving in relation to the Earth with speed 90% of light speed, then I will see time dilation in the spaceship. Person who is in the spaceship will see the same time dilation on the Earth if will be looking to the Earth at me, but this person will not see any Special relativity effects inside his spaceship.

Comment: Do I correctly understand your point: that if the Moon would be rotating around the Earth with speed close to speed of light, then we will see transverse Doppler effect (red Moon instead of white), but if the Moon is not moving and am rotating in a way, that relative Moon motion looks like it rotates with speed of light, then we will not see transverse Doppler effect?

Comment: Yes, the two scenarios are different. In one case (in an inertial frame) the Moon is going around you, but nothing else is: in particular the light from the Moon moves in straight lines from the Moon to your eye. In the other case (when you are rotating) not only is the Moon going around you, but so is everything else, including the light beams going from the Moon to your eyes. This makes a huge difference.

Comment: Looks like this is the main point. Thank you for clarifying your point. But I still do not understand what the difference is. First, Moon rotating around me is not an inertial reference frame. As they mention in Wikipedia, they consider momentarily comoving reference frame as inertial frame. Another example, If I go in a straight line in a spaceship with the speed 90% light speed. It is inertial reference frame and everything moving around me and everything will have a relativistic doppler effect in relation to my spaceship. What is a difference between moving spaceship and rotation observer?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the fact that your personal reference frame is not inertial if you are spinning, the Doppler effect depends on the relative speed of the source and the observer. In the experiment you describe, the Moon remains a fixed distance from you, the observer. That means the speed of the Moon relative you is zero, so there will be no appreciable Doppler shift.

Comment: I am talking only about Transverse Doppler effect which happens when the distance between the source and the observer is not changing.

Comment: Firstly, in the transverse Doppler effect the source usually has a varying component of velocity towards or away from you. Secondly, if you want to apply the the usual formulas for time dilation etc you have to account for the fact that you are not in an inertial frame. The simplest way is to perform calculations in your centre of mass frame then overlay the fact that you are spinning in that frame. If you do that you will find that the Moon's time dilation is negligible as is any Doppler effect.

Comment: I am talking here about the transverse Doppler effect when there is only a transverse (perpendicular) velocity component. What about that article to which I put a link in Wikipedia? It is exactly this case or Wikipedia is wrong? When you mentioned " calculations in your centre of mass frame then overlay the fact that you are spinning in that frame.", could you please give a link where a similar calculation was performed?

Comment: The transverse Doppler effect applies where the source is moving in a straight line that is not directly away or towards you. The Moon is not on such a path, but on a curve. If you do have an object on such a path, the doppler shift is blue when the object is moving towards you and red when it is moving away. At the point at which the object is  neither moving toward or away, there is no Doppler shift.

Comment: I added UDATE 1 with the cite from Wikipedia. They say there, that this curve motion will lead to transverse Doppler effect. This is what I am trying to understand, is it wikipedia wrong or I am reading it in a wrong way.

Comment: @Zlelik you are not reading it the wrong way. If a light source circles round you it will be Doppler shifted. However, the rotational speed of the Moon in an inertial reference frame is very low, so the effect will be negligible.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is what I want to understand. You idea is this if I understand you correctly: If Moon would be really rotating with speed close to speed of light, then I would see red shift, but if the Moon is not rotating fast and I am rotating in a way that the Moon speed in relation to me would be close to speed of light, then I do not see red shift. I always was thinking that in relativity we are free to choose reference frame. These 2 reference frames, standing me with rotating Moon and rotating me with slow Moon should be equivalent.